# Django To use two FilterView classes in one template

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

I am creating a search form using FilterView in the main window.
Double-click the input form in the search form in the main window to display the modal.
I want to display another FilterView class in modal.
The class of these two FilterViews is different in the model, filter, and form that they refer to.
How can this be achieved?

Views.py

```
class Filter1(FilterView):
    model = Model1
    filterset_class = Filter1
    template_name = 'filter.html'    

class Filter2(FilterView):
    model = Model2
    filterset_class = Filter2
    template_name = 'filter.html'
```

HTML(templates)

```
<form action="" method="get">

        <div class="row">
           {{filter.form|crispy}}    <-I want to use class filter 1
        </div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
・・・
{{filter.form|crispy}}    <- I want to use class filter 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it like that. One request will only call one backend API/url at a time and return one response. What you can do is to send the filters as context in one response. For example:

```
filter1 = Filter1()
filter2 = Filter2()    
context = {
    'filter1': filter1,
    'filter2': filter2,
    'result': result,
}
return render(request, '<your template name>', context)
```

This should solve your problem. Or you can use JavaScript to make an API call when the modal button is clicked and use a separate URL route to fetch a JSON response for your filter in the modal. Using JavaScript and making an AJAX request is the recommended approach because it will reduce the amount of data to be returned in one call and will not keep unnecessary texts in your response if not needed.